# Go: Comparison in maps of interface types

Tags: pointers, go

Let's say I have a lot of different struct types which all satisfy an interface, `Food`.

```
type Food interface {
    Name() string
    Tastiness() int
}

type fruit struct {
    species  string
    numSeeds int
}

type vegetable struct {
    commonName string
    weight  int
}

func (f *fruit) Name() string       { return f.species }
func (f *fruit) Tastiness() int     { return 100 - f.numSeeds }
func (v *vegetable) Name() string   { return v.commonName }
func (v *vegetable) Tastiness() int { return 1 }
```

The structs that satisfy the `Food` interface do so with functions that are `pointer receivers` because I pass them around often, which is unwieldy without pointers.

Often, I want to make comparisons between `food1` and `food2`, and so I construct maps that look like `foodmap := map[Food]bool`. What I really want to check is if the underlying structs are the same thing. But, because it's always pointers that are satisfying the interface, I can't do equality or presence tests using maps or lists if I create two of the same kind of `fruit` or `vegetable`, for example.

Is the best way to compare `Food`s to *not* use `map[Food]bool` and instead use something like `map[FoodKey]`, where any struct that satsifies `Food` provides a `FoodKey() comparisonStruct` method that returns a struct meant strictly for comparison?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*What I really want to check is if the underlying structs are the same thing*" ?

Comment: You want to make sure you are comparing two `fruit` if you just have two `Food`: Type assertion or type switch (see spec). Alternatively: reflection. Note: Your problem has nothing to do with pointers (as far as I understand your problem). Second note: "...because I pass them around often, which is unwieldy without pointers." is not true in the general case. Passing values is perfectly fine and often faster than pointers.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear: the problem does have to do with pointers because if the structs (not pointers to structs) satisfied the interface, I could do equality checks (not true with pointers). See here: http://play.golang.org/p/nWamIr0A6H. I understand that is not true in the general case, but it is true for mine since the structs are large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the best way to compare Foods to not use `map[Food]bool` and instead use something like `map[FoodKey]`, where any struct that satsifies Food provides a `FoodKey() comparisonStruct` method that returns a struct meant strictly for comparison?

I suspect it is a better approach, considering:

- comparing interface is slow ([issue 6105](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6105))
- (and that supposes [comparison operators](http://weekly.golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) are defined: see [Map Types](http://weekly.golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types))
- using an [`Equaler`](http://golang.org/doc/faq#t_and_equal_interface) (as in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/WyBUMoyxpPE)) isn't easy
- you might need to distinguish between the actual types included in the interface instances you are comparing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most efficient path here is to add an extra function to your interface like `Is(f Food) bool`, it's easy to implement, no overhead of using reflection or comparing interfaces or using a map somewhere.

Example:

```
type Food interface {
    Name() string
    Tastiness() int
    Is(f Food) bool
}
//....
func (*fruit) Is(f Food) bool   { _, ok := f.(*fruit); return ok }
//....
func (*vegetable) Is(f Food) bool   { _, ok := f.(*vegetable); return ok }
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/G__gDzcgLM)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to determine or compare the underlying structs of interfaces.

1- Use the [reflect](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package, specifically the [reflect.TypeOf](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) function, which will return the dynamic type of the interface, such as:

```
x := Food(fruit{"banana", 0})
y := Food(vegetable{"potato, 45})
return reflect.TypeOf(x) == reflect.TypeOf(y)
```

This piece of code will return false.

2- Use type assertions or a [type switch](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch), such as:

```
value, ok := yourInterface.(possibleType)
```